# Stopping at breakpoints causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, exc-bad-access, breakpoints

My app runs fine and as expected, but for some reason when I place breakpoints, stepping into/over/resuming causes the program to crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. This does not happen if I remove/disable breakpoints.

Any advice?

Comment: I'm not using threads. The code is (I guess) irrelevant as it crashes ANYWHERE I place a breakpoint, regardless. And as I said, there's no crash if there's no breakpoint?!

Comment: You might want to try cleaning and rebuilding.  Occasionally Xcode get confused and references the wrong tables, etc.

Comment: Tried cleaning and rebuilding numerous times to no avail :(

Comment: I've also started to get this issue after an upgrade to Xcode 4.2.1. The code was working perfectly beforehand with breakpoints. (You're not the only one)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From what I can see, LLDB appears to be broken in the Xcode 4.2 and 4.2.1. Switch to GDB in your "Edit Scheme" settings.

Breakpoints work just as expected after switching to GDB.

[image: Edit Scheme Dialog]

Comment: I was using LLDB and all my breakpoints worked correctly as long as I had valid expressions.  As soon as I defined an invalid one (super.position in a CCLayer) xCode would seem to close or crash.  It wouldn't even allow me to remove the invalid expression since it wouldn't break there.  When I changed over to GDB, I could see the invalid expression and delete it.  I then switched back to LLDB and the problem was gone.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: THE RIGHT ANSWER IS TO UPDATE TO XCODE 5.0.2 as another commenter pointed out below. Sorry for yelling.  =)

Comment: Where is this option located?

Answer (score 12):

To anyone that might experience the same thing with Xcode 5.0.1 and Mavericks:
Try deleting all your schemes and auto create them again - that fixed it for me.

Comment: Recreating the schemes didn't work for me.  I did notice that it happens on my iOS 6 devices (iPhone 5, iPad 2), but not my iOS 7 device (iPhone 4s).

Comment: Weird, it was happening on my iOS 6 iPad 2. Try deleting and adding the breakpoints after you've just recreating the schemes.

Comment: It's working now but I'm not sure why.  I tried many things... deleting the app from my device, rebooting it, rebooting the Mac, etc.  Then I ran into another unrelated problem (as far as I know) where Xcode would never complete a build.  Afraid I don't remember how I found it, but it turned out my keychain was messed up with 46,000 certs & 93,000 keys named com.apple.ubiquity.peer-uuid.  It took close to an hour just to open keychain!  Here's a link to the page that helped me solve it: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3396579?start=0&tstart=0 Now, both problems are fixed.  Go Figure!

Comment: Ah, found the SO question that led me to the keychain problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404560/xcode-long-freezes-after-upgrading-to-4-3-2/10404859#10404859

Comment: I also tried removing and adding all schemes but it didn't solve my problem. ugghhh!

Comment: Looks like the best thing right now is to revert to Xcode 5.0.0 - https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode you can download it from here. And just wait for Apple to release 5.0.2.

Comment: Apple released 5.0.2 and the bug is fixed.

Comment: 5.0.2 Fixed it for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Where you using lldb instead of gdb ? I'm getting this systematically with Xcode 4.2.1 and lldb. Switching back to gdb (booooo) solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Xcode 4.3.2 and Xcode update the debug to LLDB automatically(A popup dialog and I confirm it). This is really a nightmare, it crash when I step into any function call 8-9 out of 10.

Change back to GDB seems better now!

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug with XCode 5.0.1 and Mavericks. Apple released 5.0.2 and the bug is fixed!

Answer (score 0):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means you have a memory problem somewhere - very likely that something is being released when you expect it to still be around (perhaps the result of an `autorelease`). Run the [static analyzer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009984-CH3-SW22) to find it. I imagine you're seeing the crash because the debugger is aggressively occupying memory when you load breakpoints and hence flagging a problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'm having the same problem. I can take code that I know is correct and if I step into it with lldb, it crashes after reaching a breakpoint. I also get output like this when I try to print any locals

```
(lldb) p self
error: use of undeclared identifier 'self'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

Looks like lldb is busted in Xcode 4.2.1. The only advice I have is switch back to gdb for now.